# Rename an activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I have added an empty activity in option menu settings. When I am clicking on settings an activity opens, named My Application, which is my application name. I want the name to be Settings. Can anyone help? I'm using Android studio.

Comment: Select the activity name and press "Control + F6" (in windows) or "CMD + F6" (in mac). A dialog will come, give new name to that activity and press OK.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error do you get (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your activity title using this code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My title");
```

Comment: Thanks @v6kr, that solved my  issue, but it is telling that some exception may happen due to setTitle(). If you want the exact message I shall post later.

Comment: NullPointerException  occurs in that case when you could be using a NoActionBar theme and trying to set title . for that reason IDE show warnings. Just ignore that warning.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at your androidManifest.xml configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the activity file from the project structure.
Press "Shift + F6 ", you will be asked to rename the activity.
Enter the new name and press Enter.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Find your activity declaration and add `android:label="Settings"` to activity tag.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/settings_label"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Sue Yine. That really worked. I have one more question. If I choose"ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" theme an error occurs, but if I add the theme to the toolbar in .xml file that is fine. Can you clarify please?

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question. If you have another question, accept this answer and post a new question with sample code and error log.

Answer (score 0):

Select the activity name in the project explorer and press "Shift + F6" (in windows) or "CMD + F6" (in mac). A dialog will come, give new name to that activity and press OK. This will make changes in all the required places.

Comment: Do you mean to stay in the settingsactivity.java file and then Ctrl+f6?

Comment: yes, stay there and then find the same file in your project explorer.